# Simplify ¬(s∨(w∧¬s)) to ¬s∧¬w

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Simplify ¬(s∨(w∧¬s)) to ¬s∧¬w

¬(s∨(w∧¬s)) De morgans

¬s∧¬(w∧¬s) De morgans
¬s∧(¬w∨¬¬s) Distributive
(¬s∧¬w)∨(¬s∧¬¬s) Double Negation
(¬s∧¬w)∨(¬s∧s) Commutative
(¬s∧¬w)∨(s∧¬s) Complement
(¬s∧¬w)∨F

This is where im at with the new problem..I thought it would just be ¬s∧¬w but my online book is still prompting me to choose a propositional law to make it ¬s∧¬w

Comment: What do you mean by "to?"

Comment: I suspect this is to show logical equivalence between the two, @ThomasAndrews

Comment: yes showing logical equivalence

Comment: Please don't change the question completely (as in [revision 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4530959/revisions)). Now all the existing answers become irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

How you apply De Morgans in the second step is wrong it should be
\begin{equation}
 \neg m \lor (\neg n \land \neg\neg m) ;De\_Moargans\\
  (\neg m \lor \neg n)\land(\neg m \lor m); Distributive\_property
\end{equation}

Comment: Im doing this on a online textbook so since i have inactive for so long, it refreshed and gave me a new problem so this is what i have now

Simplify ¬(s∨(w∧¬s)) to ¬s∧¬w //
¬(s∨(w∧¬s)) //
¬s∧¬(w∧¬s) //
¬s∧(¬w∨¬¬s) //
(¬s∧¬w)∨(¬s∧¬¬s) //
(¬s∧¬w)∨(¬s∧s) //
(¬s∧¬w)∨(s∧¬s) //
(¬s∧¬w)∨F

Comment: I cant believe how stuck im getting on this

Answer (score 0):

$\neg m\lor(\neg n\land m)$

$\iff (\neg m\lor\neg n)\land (\neg m\lor m)$, because of the distributive law

$\iff (\neg m\lor\neg n)\land (\text{true})$

$\iff (\neg m\lor\neg n)$

Comment: So the true or false would just automatically cancel out and go away? I dont know why the online text book is not taking it

Comment: @frogholler yes, $x\land \text{true}$ is always equivalent to $x$, because $\text{true}\land \text{true}$ is equivalent to true, and $\text{true}\land \text{false}$ is equivalent to false, so basically the "true" value just cancels out. A similiar argument also explains why $x\lor \text{false}$ is equivalent to x as well.